# select() and poll() missing a closed pipe on Mac OS

Tags: c, macos, unix, select, file-descriptor

I'm seeing behavior from both select() and poll() on Mac OS 10.9 which I cannot explain. Help me understand what I might be doing wrong, or if this could be an OS bug (hard to believe...)

**What I'm Doing**

My program watches for file descriptors to become readable in a background thread using select() or poll(). The bug is the same with either implementation, so I'll just describe what happens with poll.

The file descriptor in question is created with forkpty(), so it is one end of a pseudoterminal. I call execvp() to run a shell in the child process, and eventually it terminates. This causes the file descriptor in the parent to produce an end-of-file result from read() after all buffered output is read (that is, read returns 0).

The normal course of operation is to alternate calls to poll() with calls to read() on this file descriptor. Eventually read() returns 0 and I can clean up, knowing the child process is done.

**What's Wrong**

Here's what's unexpected: sometimes poll() will not return when the subprocess has finished and the file descriptor is in an EOF state.

**Why I Think poll() is Misbehaving**

Here's a session in lldb to demonstrate. I stopped it while blocked in poll() after the child process finished.

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #11: tid = 0x24ee79, 0x00007fff904a594a libsystem_kernel.dylib`poll + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff904a594a libsystem_kernel.dylib`poll + 10
  * frame #1: 0x00000001001f2672 iTerm`-[iTermPollHelper poll](self=0x000060800042db00, _cmd=0x00007fff9349800b) + 194 at iTermPollHelper.m:117
    frame #2: 0x000000010014a87b iTerm`-[TaskNotifier run](self=0x000060000045c620, _cmd=0x00007fff8fda8066) + 4251 at TaskNotifier.m:216
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8c86c76b Foundation`__NSThread__main__ + 1318
    frame #4: 0x00007fff934a8899 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 138
    frame #5: 0x00007fff934a872a libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 137
```

Ok, so thread 11 is blocking in poll(). Here's what my call to poll looks like:

```
numDescriptors = poll(pollfds, count, -1);
```

Let's examine it:

```
(lldb) p count
(int) $2 = 2
(lldb) p pollfds[0]
(pollfd) $3 = (fd = 6, events = 1, revents = 0)
(lldb) p pollfds[1]
(pollfd) $4 = (fd = 5, events = 1, revents = 0)
```

The events field's value of 1 corresponds to POLLIN. In this case, fd 5 is the one of interest. We've proven that poll() is watching file descriptor 5, and if it's in an EOF state, poll should have returned by now. I can do this:

```
(lldb) finish
```

and poll() won't return. So it's definitely blocked, and must believe there is nothing to read on fd 5.

My program includes this function:

```
void TryReadingFromFd(int fd) {
    char buffer[1];
    int n = read(fd, buffer, 1);
    NSLog(@"Read returns %d, errno=%d", n, errno);
}
```

While still stopped in poll(), I run this from the debugger:

```
(lldb) expr (void)TryReadingFromFd(5)
2014-03-26 21:53:43.684 iTerm[48604:af07] Read returns 0, errno=35
```

If read returns 0, that's an end-of-file condition that poll should have caught.

**Futher Evidence**

If I give poll() a timeout and run it in a loop, like this:

```
do {
  numDescriptors = poll(pollfds, count, 1000);
} while (numDescriptors == 0);
```

then the problem goes away, and I can see poll() block and then find the EOF'ed file descriptor, but never with more than a 1 second delay. Presumably poll() works when the file descriptor is already closed before it's called but gets confused when it closes while already in poll().

**What Else Might be Going On?**

This is a complex program, and I can't reproduce this issue in a trivially small example. So something might happen on the main thread to confuse the issue. I'm hoping someone could suggest what could interfere with poll() in such a way. Removing code from the main thread makes the problem happen less frequently, so I can't take things out until I find a smoking gun.

**Source**
If you're really curious, the source code can be found here (note the branch is "pollHelper"):
https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/tree/pollHelper

To reproduce, open a new terminal and close with Control-D. It happens about 20-30% of the time for me.

Running the following program in the background makes it happen much more often on my 2013 13" Macbook Pro:

```
int main() { while (1); return 0; }
```

Comment: Use `errno`  with `perror` when `poll` fails

Comment: It's unclear what the order if things are. If read() did return 0, you're not guaranteed that poll/select will signal anything if you watch the file descriptor again after you have a read() that returned 0.

Comment: Did you set the filedescriptors to non-blocking before poll/select ?

Comment: To clarify: read() doesn't return 0 when this bug is evident. The last call to read() returns -1 with errno=EAGAIN, and then poll blocks eternally. The file descriptors are non-blocking [I do fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,O_NONBLOCK) just after forkpty returns]. There's no way there's a stray read() call, or data would get dropped during normal operation.

Comment: I haven't looked at your full source, since it is really large, but terminal drivers sometimes do drop data intentionally, for debouncing purposes. As a pure guess, I suspect a bug where some code has a stale file descriptor that matches the one you are polling.

Comment: While reading the `poll()` man page, I see `POLLPRI` having a specific purpose for pseudoterminals. Did you try to add that to your event mask?

Comment: POLLPRI seems to have a specific purpose in Linux for packet-mode psuedoterminals, but that's not the case here. I wonder if it would be possible to use dtrace to see if there's an unexpected read(2) call being made...

Comment: Is it hard to (temporally) remove the multithreading and test it as a monolithic server? The bug could be caused by (lack of) thread synchronisation.

Comment: I can't get it to happen when I poll in the main loop (I set it up to poll from a timer every 10ms with poll blocking for up to 100ms). I think synchronization issues are likely here, although I'm still puzzled by why poll wouldn't return when there is a file descriptor that's ready to read.